# why I can not use ALAnimationSpeech API to make Nao to do the specific gesture,like ^start()

Tags: python, text-to-speech, nao-robot

```
animatedSpeechProxy = ALProxy("ALAnimatedSpeech","10.10.10.106",9559)
animatedSpeechProxy.declareAnimationsPackage("Stand")
animatedSpeechProxy.say("Hello! ^start(animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1) Nice to meet you ^wait(animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1)")
```

The Nao robot can do random gestures during speech (these gestures are from the default package of `ALAnimationSpeech`), but it cannot do the specific gesture I want it to do. In other words, I think the gesture related to the path in `^start()` has not been found.

The way that I found the path of the gesture:

[image: path]

[image: path2]

My robot is sitting while doing a gesture. Will this affect the execution of this gesture(`^start(animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1)`)?

Could someone help me see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, the animations are different if the robot is standing or sitting.
As its path suggest, the animation `animations/Stand/Gestures/Hey_1` is for when the robot is standing.

Please [find an animation](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao-naoqi-2-1/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-framework/naoqi-apis/naoqi-audio/alanimatedspeech-0#animated-speech-list-behaviors-nao) which path starts with `animations/Sit/`.